# Command Prompt Read Variable from file and put inside a Loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, command-prompt

I am trying to achieve something that using Command Prompt, I have some understanding on command prompt code but however I feel quite confusing and need explanation on it.

What I am trying to achieve is

1) Read variable from a text file, for example:

- Host1.domain.com
- Host2
- Comp1.sub.domain.com
- Example4

2) After getting this variable, put inside a command, let say Ping (each open up in a separate command window):

- Ping Host1.domain.com
- ping host2
- ping comp1.sub.domain.com
- ping example4

3) However I do not want a simple Ping, I want those hostname being put inside a Loop (the Loop is inside that separate command window previously):

:loop
ping Host1.domain.com
goto loop

I am aware that I can use ping -t, however this is just an example, and ping -t won't do the job, as I want to test DNS resolution, I have other script that keep flushing DNS and using loop.

Thank you for in advance for anyone that can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (tested)-

```
echo.:loop >png_tmp.bat
echo.ping %%1 >>png_tmp.bat
echo.goto :loop >>png_tmp.bat

for /f "delims=" %%i in (input.txt) do (start png_tmp.bat %%i)
```

Cheers,
G

Comment: Hi, Thanks your script works perfectly, however I would like to know the logic behind.        
echo.ping %%1 >>png_tmp.bat        
Why the %1 can be the list entry?        
Thanks

Comment: As you can see we are creating a temporary batch file which accepts the input arguments. We are  then putting your hostname inside the for loop which will start the batch file and pass the hostname as an argument. %1 can't be list entry as you want to loop the ping indefinitely and that is not achievable in single line commands.